# Implement Drag and Drop without using Context Menu using Shell extension in C++

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, drag-and-drop

HI,

I want to implement Drag and Drop without using Context Menu using Shell extension in C++
Currently I am refering to Shell extension article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide6.aspx

But this article in turn is using Cookies and all .. I am not able to understand that. My requirement is just when I want to drag and drop files(FTP Scenario)
Any help or code snippet...
Thanks.

Comment: This looks like it's windows-specific, so I tagged it as such.  Please, fix it if I'm not correct.

Comment: Drag&Drop operations seldom use the context menu (I think you may have confused this with Copy&Paste). Could you please try to explain in a little bit more detail what exactly you are trying to accomplish?
Do you just want to be able to drop files into your application? Do you want Drag&drop to work both ways? If you are using MFC, Drag&Drop can be implemented quite easy.
Have a look at the following MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96826a87(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Yes i want to implemet both way ( i am using FTP) can u pls provide some sample code in MFC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this [OLE Drag and Drop](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/dragdrop/1) article is pretty good for beginners. Also a good source is [Drag and Drop How-to Topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746687.aspx) on MSDN. Good luck.